# Mark multiple locations in Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am using `Google map api v3` to plot markers of location array. My script is

```
function OnSuccess(response) {

            var markers = response.d.split('^^');
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.474634, -0.195791);
            var mapOptions1 = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: latlng
            }
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions1);
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i];
                
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': data }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: data  
                        });
                       

                    } else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            }
            (function (marker, data) {

                // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
```

where `markers` variable is bringing proper data, my test data is array of 5 elements

1. The Game Larder, 24 The Parade, Claygate, Surrey,KT10 0NU
2. 24 The Parade, Claygate, Esher, Surrey KT10 0NU
3. Card Collection, 14 The Parade, Claygate, ESHER, KT10 0NU
4. 16A The Parade, Claygate, ESHER, KT10 0NU

   and same is coming into array `markers` however it is plotting only two markers. What could be wrong here

**Solution**

I was entering locations which are very close to each other e.g 1 and 2 point which gives same `latlong` hence mark as one place. I found `latlong` [here](http://www.latlong.net). Thanks for answers btw :)

Comment: What does your `markers` array look like?  What do you get as the `status` for each of those addresses? (i.e. do all your addresses correctly get a location from the geocoder?)

Comment: follow my answer in here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915353/multiple-markers-and-infowindows-on-google-maps-using-mysql/23915856#23915856

Comment: @duncan: Marker array is a array of of all 5 locations, loop is iterating five time, alert() for status not displaying popup. Yes, I get all locations in marker array

Comment: @HoangHieu: I am sorry I did not tagged `asp.net` in my question and you gave result in php. I am big big zero in php. Do you have answer in C# code or can you please explain algo so that I can correct it.

Comment: it is javascript, in ASP.nET it ok...

Comment: But your answer has some php tag, right?

Comment: My answer has some php tag, are you know java script can be run on ASP.net and php, java script is client function and it's running on browser, Don't have any difference when run java script between ASP.NET and PHP.

Comment: I don't vote down you...

Answer (score 1):

In page.aspx. insert tag `<div id="map-canvas" ></div>`

view source page.aspx and insert script into it>

```
var lis_marker = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i];

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': data }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);


                    lis_marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: data  
                    });


                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
```

there are difference with your code:

1: `var lis_marker = new Array();`

2:  `lis_marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({...});`

Comment: I applied the same in case if InfoWindow but it gives error "Invalid token [" on lis_marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({...});

Comment: As it was a different question, I asked it somewhere else and got solution, thank you @HoangHieu