# google maps marker added using json.parse

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-maps-api-3

considering the below code I've tried to print in console the length of the parsed array and that process works properly, now even if I already have the array which adds the information parsed through the json file loaded in the js code, I am unable to display the array of markers inside the map

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.90832, 12.52407)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "json/prova.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        arr[i].title +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].latitude +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].longitude +
        "</td></tr>"
  ;
  //console.log(arr.length);
    }
    out += "</table>"
    // document.getElementById("map-canvas").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```css
    html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
         <title>Simple Map</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
         <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&amp;key=AIzaSyD3Xz7-z7U_XzZiaOlx9khhtFSld8vd0k4"></script>
        <script src="js/prova_simple.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>

  <h1>Customers</h1>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide sample JSON and a code snippet (a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that works (or at least demonstrates the issue) without javascript errors

Comment: [
{
"title": "Coop.Sociale Prassi e Ricerca Onlus", 
"latitude": 41.9114145,
"longitude": 12.524204
},
{
"title": "Astronave", 
"latitude": 41.912333,
"longitude": 12.525531
},
{
"title": "Casa", 
"latitude": 41.877719,
"longitude": 12.558317
}
]

Comment: I have tested the json file and it works

Comment: you didn't try to create any markers inside your code

Comment: you're right the fact is that I don't know where to try to create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm!!!. Your json have lat and lng of marker, you can try add multiple marker to google map with example code hear

```
var infowindow = [];
var marker = [];
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            (function(i){ //new line 
            infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: arr[i].title
            });
            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    title: arr[i].title,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,                        
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].latitude,arr[i].longitude)
                });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
               infowindow[i].open(map,this);
            });
            })(i); //new line
    }
}
```

Comment: could you suggest me the right part of the code where to add your snippet? by the way thanks for your reply

Comment: I've tryed copy and past as a matter of face I'm unawere of the position of this snippet above or below the ajax request? i've tried to insert this portion inside the ajax request beacuse there is the arr variable which I've declared inside the ajax request anyway I can't add no markers , I ran the code on my mirror server but nothing happens

Comment: ahh. sorry about it, please remove line **icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon),**

Comment: I've tried to use the capitol letter I to replace info with Info but again my friend nothing happens, and believe me I've tried your update answer the fact is the map is centered correctly i can get the length of the array using console.log so i assume the ajax request works properly but I am unable to add those markers on the map I'm pretty sure I'm make some stupid mistake but I don't know where, thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't tried to do that, I've used my mirror server would you suggest me to use the fiddle? at any rate in debug I can see the Info or infowindon no matter the capital letter is undefined one moment I verify the code on the fiddle

Comment: can you link me the jsfiddle succeeded attempt

Comment: flow this answer  **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629603/mark-multiple-locations-in-google-map/24652060#24652060**,
i don't have any data json :|

Comment: just in case I flow that answer that is a different example from mine, as you said you don't have any daya json might that be useful to me considering that difference?

Comment: I mean,I don't have any data json for example, if you can send me it, I think, I can demo that for you :)